# Colorizing methods on Visual Studio 2013 with Roslyn C# Colorizer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Was anyone able to get the Roslyn C# Colorizer VS extension working?

I've installed it and under settings I can customize the colors and everything however I'm not seeing the results, I was particularly looking to colorize method calls just like it is on the demo screenshot from the gallery:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5b1a493f-740e-4428-9fe9-65b0028380f3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Roslyn installed.  This means either installing Visual Studio 2014 or installing the End User Preview for Visual Studio 2013.  https://roslyn.codeplex.com/  Note: the End User Preview is no longer updated, so if you want to use this with the latest features then you will need Visual Studio 2014.

Comment: Thanks, will wait for VS 2014 to be released then.

Comment: I should note that the plug-in doesn't appear to work with the latest VS2014 CTP.

Comment: Is the plug-in's source code published somewhere? The author doesn't seem to be interested in the project anymore, so I wouldn't count on it to come back to life again. Will VS 2015 offer such extended highlighting features on its own?